# What is the syntax for using an MVC model in an HTML style attribute?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model, styles

I have code that looks like this:

```
<label>@Model.Color</label>
<label style="background-color:#FFFFFF; height:10px;"></label>
```

This makes a label that says "#000000", which is the content of the string held in Model.Color.  And a second label that has a white background color.

What I want to do is use the contents of Model.Color to set the background of the second label.

I would've thought it would be something like this:

```
<label style="background-color:@Model.Color; height:10px;"></label>
```

But it doesn't work.  What is the appropriate strategy for this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
<label style="background-color:@(Model.Color); height:10px;"></label>
```